# Translation of CUDA inline asm from GAS to Intel

Tags: c, linux, windows, cuda, inline-assembly

I have some C-CUDA code that contains [inline PTX assembly](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html), which compiles OK on Linux with g++ backend.

I need to build it under Windows, and clearly MSVC backend does not recognize inline asm properly - gives errors like "not an asm string". I assume it has to do with syntax this PTX assembly is written, for example:

```
    asm volatile ("subc.cc.u32 %0, %0, "q2_s";": "+r"(c[2]));
    asm volatile ("subc.cc.u32 %0, %0, "q3_s";": "+r"(c[3]));
```

I don't know much about assembly, and am wondering - is there some translator from GAS(at&t) style to Intel syntax?

Or is there some workaround to build CUDA kernels to PTX on Linux, and then build PTX & link to remaining code on Windows?
I've tried that, but PTX compiler on linux gives kernel functions some unrecognizable _Z-starting names and linker does not know how to link the stuff.

Comment: why not just install the CUDA toolchain on windows? It is the only supported method, and it is integrated into MSVC/Visual Studio

Comment: I have a CUDA toolchain on Windows with MSVC. Problem is - MSVC does not recognize inline asm (like examples above) - so I either have to rewrite it in MSVC-recognizable syntax (which I have no clue how to do) or compile kernels to PTX in Linux and then somehow link this PTX to rest of the code on Windows...

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to compile CUDA source code with MSVC which obviously won't work. You have to compile your CUDA sources with nvcc or some other compiler that supports CUDA (clang would be the only alternative I'm currently aware of). As far as I know, g++ does currently not support CUDA either by the way, it's unclear to me how that is supposed to work on Linux as you claim…

Comment: I guess what's needed here is a clear description of how exactly you're currently trying to build your code…

Comment: when I say MSVC or g++ I, of course, mean nvcc with MSVC or g++ backend    (nvcc is not really a standalone compiler, it relies on backend compilers)

Comment: I use cuda's asm with visual studio all the time.  If this isn't working for you, I'm guessing you haven't got your build environment set up correctly.  Can you tell us more about your project?  Is this in a .cu file?  When you build, do you see the `nvcc` command being executed?  Is the "error" an actual build error?  Or just an intellisense error?

Comment: Your problem description makes no sense. CUDA inline assembler on device code never gets anywhere near the host compiler unless you do something like put it in a `__host__ __device__`  function and that should fail on every platform. Can you provide an [MCVE] rather than a lot of hand waving?

Comment: OK, thanks to everybody and sorry for my silly explanations, turns out these assembly instructions relied on right preprocessing, and it somehow worked on Linux but gave "expected an asm string" on Windows, for example for instructions above it used this define   `#define q2_s              "0xAF48A03B"` . So I just hardcoded these hex values in asm strings and everything compiled well on Windows.

Comment: @user11371337: Please add your diagnosis of the problem and solution as a short answer to this question for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, problem was not with inline asm, but with preprocessing, e.g. for example, asm string

```
asm volatile ("subc.cc.u32 %0, %0, "q2_s";": "+r"(c[2]));
```

relied on this define

```
#define q2_s "0xAF48A03B"
```

On Linux it compiled without errors, but on Windows gave "expected an asm string" error.
So, workaround for Windows was just to hardcode hex values in asm strings, and it has nothing to do with assembly syntax, sorry for misguiding.